# Error at ps.executeQuery(sql) while using sql with timestamps

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc, timestamp

I am getting dates from JSP and casting them into timestamp

```
DBConnection    = ConnMgr.getConnection();       
Timestamp timestamp1 = new java.sql.Timestamp(date1.getTime());
Timestamp timestamp2 = new java.sql.Timestamp(date2.getTime());
```

I have a sql statement and prepared staement as follows

```
String sql      = " select * from images where uploadedOn>=? and uploadedOn<=?;";
ps              = DBConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setTimestamp(1, timestamp1);
ps.setTimestamp(2, timestamp2);
System.out.println(ps);
```

This print statement is printing this is in console

```
select * from images where uploadedOn>='2015-02-02 00:00:00' and uploadedOn<='2015-02-05 00:00:00';
```

which is working fine when copied into the mySQL workbenck and run. But it is giving error in the following statement

```
rs              = ps.executeQuery(sql);
```

The error is

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and uploadedOn<=?' at line 1
```

Struggling with this since yesterday. Can any one help me to solve this out?

Comment: Add blanks between operator and values.

Comment: select * from images where uploadedOn >= '2015-02-02 00:00:00' and uploadedOn <= '2015-02-05 00:00:00';

even now same problem

Comment: Is `DBConnection` a class that you have written? if yes please show the code.

Comment: I got the error. I replaced `ps.executeQuery(sql);` with `ps.executeQuery();` and its working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is already prepared you don't need to execute another query

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```